# Laravel 5 Queue Dispatcher not instantiating with Property

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, queue

So to me this registration email queue seems quite simple, I must be missing something somewhere!

```
namespace App\Jobs;     
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;  
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;  
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;  
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;  
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;  
use Mail;  
use App\Mail\EmailVerification;  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class SendVerificationEmail implements ShouldQueue  
{  
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;  
    protected $user;  

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = new EmailVerification($this->user);
        Log::alert('Showing user profile: '.json_encode($this->user));
        $user = $this->user;
        $to = "xxxx@gmail.com";
        if(isset($user->email)){
            $to = $user->email;
        }
        Mail::to( $to )->send($email);
    }
}
```

The $this->user property is empty even though it is a full object when instantiated which happens here:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
    dd($user); //at this moment $user is everything it's supposed to be;
    dispatch(new SendVerificationEmail($user)); // it is now null??
    return view('email.verification');
}
```

The Handle() function is a callback for the dispatch() but why it doesnt get passed the user object??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to type hint `$user` as follows:

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    // do a var dump here, is it populated?
}
```